# Why does this flash policy module (express middleware) use _.clone() in Sails.js?

Tags: node.js, session, express, sails.js, middleware

From a [tutorial on Sails](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_wL2cS0GmJQ&list=PLf8i4fc0zJBzLhOe6FwHpGhBDgqwInJWZ&index=10), this is a [Sails policy](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Policies) - essentially Express middleware:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.flash = {};

  if (!req.session.flash) return next();

  res.locals.flash = _.clone(req.session.flash)

  // clear flash
  req.session.flash = {};

  next();
};
```

I'm totally lost:

What's the difference between `req.locals.flash` and `req.session.flash`?

Why do the response locals.flash have to be cleared right off the bat?

Why are response locals filled with cloned request session flash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the difference between req.locals.flash and req.session.flash?

> req.locals.flash will available in its view, but the req,session
>   relates with the session of browser.

More info [locals](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.locals) vs [session](http://expressjs-book.com/forums/topic/express-js-sessions-a-detailed-tutorial/)

Why do the response locals.flash have to be cleared right off the bat?

> Make sure that the error message just display one time only.

Why are response locals filled with cloned request session flash?

> Cause if not the locals will keep the pointer of the session. So if
>   the "req.session.flash = {};", the locals will also be empty

Answer (score 0):

This is a policy, it will be invoked each time you visit a url(depends on your config/policies.js), what it does is to **consume** the message.

Clearing **req**.session.flash is to make sure the message is only displayed once, clearly you don't want to be haunted by the message again and again. :D

Hope that helps.